# Why is NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces not releasing memory after use

Tags: vb.net

My program checks every two seconds whether the network adapter OperationalStatus has changed.

Memory usage increases by 500k after each call and the execution time rises by at least 10ms.

This only happens in a stand alone release version.
In the debugger everything is fine.
Running the program in a memory profiler is also no problem.

Shown simplified, even this example does it as well:-

```
Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
    For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics
    Next
End Sub
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Framework 4 client profile x86

Comment: What you're doing here is called *polling*, and it is [*terrible design*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060124-17/?p=32553).

Comment: Yes it is a terrible design, and if I could find a better method I would use it. Polling shouldn't bring my computer to its knees after two hours though, should it.